# How detect a change on state of flutter widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need to detect when my *phoneCall* variable changes state this to detect when the call ended and show a modal to the user so he can rate the call. This is the widget code.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:avanx/flutter/loading_view.dart';
import 'package:avanx/globals.dart';
import 'package:avanx/models/group.dart';
import 'package:avanx/models/prospect.dart';
import 'package:cool_alert/cool_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter_phone_state/flutter_phone_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import '../flutter/theme.dart';
import 'package:avanx/flutter/input_widget.dart';
import '../flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:avanx/flutter/drawer_widget.dart';
import 'package:loading_animations/loading_animations.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LeadsHomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  LeadsHomeWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LeadsHomeWidgetState createState() => _LeadsHomeWidgetState();
}

class _LeadsHomeWidgetState extends State<LeadsHomeWidget> {
  List<dynamic> _leads = [];
  List<dynamic> _groups;

  var phoneCall;

  TextEditingController textController;
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  String _search = '';

  _initCall(_number) async {
    setState(() {
      phoneCall = FlutterPhoneState.startPhoneCall(_number);
    });
  }

  showCallInfo() {
    print(phoneCall
        .status); // ringing, dialing, cancelled, error, connecting, connected, timedOut, disconnected
    print(phoneCall.isComplete); // Whether the call is complete
    print(phoneCall
        .events); // A list of call events related to this specific call
  }

  // Metodo para la obtención de los grupos existentes.
  getGroups() async {
    print("hello");
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(Globals.avanx + '/groups'),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var groupsList = json.decode(response.body)['groups'];
      List<dynamic> groups =
          groupsList.map((element) => new Group.fromJson(element)).toList();

      setState(() {
        _groups = groups;
      });
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load groups');
    }
  }

  getLeads(name) async {
    if (name != '') {
      String auth = Globals.authUser.user.id.toString();

      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(Globals.avanx + '/prospects/search/$auth'),
          body: {'name': name},
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var leadsList = json.decode(response.body)['leads'];
        List<dynamic> leads =
            leadsList.map((element) => new Prospect.fromJson(element)).toList();

        setState(() {
          _leads = leads;
        });
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load leads');
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _leads = [];
      });
    }
  }

  deleteModal(id) {
    CoolAlert.show(
        context: context,
        animType: null,
        type: CoolAlertType.warning,
        title: '¿Estas Seguro?',
        text: "Esta acción no se puede reversar.",
        backgroundColor: Color(0xBF35126A),
        confirmBtnText: 'Confirmar',
        confirmBtnColor: Color(0xBF35126A),
        showCancelBtn: true,
        cancelBtnText: 'Cancelar',
        onConfirmBtnTap: () {
          deleteLead(id);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        });
  }

  deleteLead(id) async {
    final response = await http.delete(
        Uri.parse(Globals.avanx + '/prospects/$id'),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      _search = '';
      this.getLeads(_search);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load leads');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    textController = TextEditingController();
    this.getGroups();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: FlutterTheme.tertiaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: FlutterTheme.primaryColor,
        title: Text(
          'Prospectos',
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: DrawerWidget(),
      body: _groups == null
          ? LoadingWidget()
          : Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 10, 30, 0),
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  children: _groups == null
                      ? []
                      : [
                          Form(
                            key: _formKey,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  flex: 2,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding:
                                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                    child: InputWidget(
                                      label: 'Buscar prospecto?',
                                      keyBoardType: TextInputType.text,
                                      onChanged: (text) {
                                        _search = text;
                                      },
                                      validator: (text) {
                                        if (text.trim().length == 0) {
                                          return "input data";
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Buscar',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: FlutterTheme.primaryColor),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      getLeads(_search);
                                    },
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1.5,
                                        color: FlutterTheme.primaryColor,
                                      ),
                                      primary: Colors.white,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          phoneCall.isComplete
                              ? Container(
                                  child: Text('The call is end!!'),
                                )
                              : Container(),
                          for (var lead in _leads ?? [])
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                              child: Slidable(
                                actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
                                actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                          'https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=' +
                                              lead.name +
                                              '&background=35126A&color=fff&size=128'),
                                    ),
                                    title: Text(lead.name),
                                    subtitle: Text(
                                      'Grupo: ' + lead.group.name,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
                                    ),
                                    trailing: Container(
                                      width: 100,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                _initCall(lead.phone);
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.phone,
                                                size: 35,
                                                color: Color(0xFF35126A),
                                              )),
                                          IconButton(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                showCallInfo();
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.mail_outline,
                                                size: 35,
                                                color: Color(0xFF35126A),
                                              )),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                secondaryActions: <Widget>[
                                  IconSlideAction(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'leads_edit',
                                          arguments: lead);
                                    },
                                    caption: 'Edit',
                                    color: Color(0xFF35126A),
                                    icon: Icons.edit,
                                  ),
                                  IconSlideAction(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      deleteModal(lead.id);
                                    },
                                    caption: 'Delete',
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    icon: Icons.delete,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
                            child: ButtonWidget(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'leads_add_new');
                              },
                              text: 'Agregar Nuevo',
                              options: ButtonOptions(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 40,
                                color: FlutterTheme.tertiaryColor,
                                textStyle: FlutterTheme.subtitle2.override(
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                  color: FlutterTheme.primaryColor,
                                ),
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: FlutterTheme.primaryColor,
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: 30,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
                            child: Text(
                              'Grupos',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: FlutterTheme.bodyText1.override(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                color: Color(0xBF35126A),
                                fontSize: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          for (var group in _groups)
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
                              child: ButtonWidget(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'leads_list',
                                      arguments: group);
                                },
                                text: group.name,
                                options: ButtonOptions(
                                  width: 130,
                                  height: 40,
                                  color: FlutterTheme.primaryColor,
                                  textStyle: FlutterTheme.subtitle2.override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.transparent,
                                    width: 1,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: 30,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                        ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

The function _initCall is the one in charge of initializing the call, so the variable *phoneCall* will have the information of the state of the call, I want to launch a modal when the call finishes.

Comment: The solution is right there on the flutter_phone_state pub page: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phone_state

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).